# How can I find out whether Node.js HTTPS request error was caused by a missing host or a missing proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I have a script that requests a given URL via a proxy.  A failure to connect to the proxy gives an identical error to a failure to connect to the URL over a successful proxy connection.

This code:

```
var opts = url.parse("https://192.168.0.10/");//this ip address doesn't resolve anywhere
opts.agent = new SocksProxyAgent("socks4://works.local:1080");//this proxy works
    
https.get(opts, function (resp) {

    //successful request is dealt with

}).on("error", function (err) {console.log(err)});
```

Produces this output:

```
SocksClientError: Proxy connection timed out
#I cutout the stack trace for brevity
  options: {
    proxy: { host: 'works.local', port: 1080, type: 4 },
    destination: { host: '192.168.0.10', port: 443 },
    command: 'connect',
    timeout: undefined
  }
```

If I run the same code but instead with a working URL, and a deliberately non-resolving proxy, I get an identical error message.

Is there a convenient way of being more specific about what is broken, whether a failure to connect to the proxy, or a failure to connect to the target URL?